# prepare JSON to post to elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm working on get performance metric from CloudLinux that run in a xenserver pool.

since currently I post data to influxdb, here is my dictionary for each influxdb record

```
{
    "fields": {
        "lNETI": 0,
        "lNETO": 0,
        "lEP": 20,
        "lMEM": 262144,
        "lCPUW": 100,
        "CPU": 0,
        "lCPU": 10000,
        "lNPROC": 100,
        "lIO": 1024,
        "lIOPS": 1024,
        "nCPU": 1,
        "NPROC": 0,
        "NETO": 0,
        "fMEMPHY": 0,
        "NETI": 0,
        "fMEM": 0,
        "IOPS": 0,
        "IO": 0,
        "fNPROC": 0,
        "EP": 0,
        "MEM": 0,
        "MEMPHY": 0,
        "fEP": 0,
        "lMEMPHY": 262144
    },
    "time": "2018-05-24T20:38:33Z",
    "tags": {
        "vm": "myvmid",
        "host": "cpanel.bino.net",
        "user": "johndoe",
        "xpool": "mypool"
    },
    "measurement": "lve"
}
```

My question : how is the proper json for elasticsearch base on above data ?

Comment: did you try indexing it?

Comment: what's your index, document and expected field set?

Comment: try experimenting with indexing and querying elasticsearch until you understand it, then design your json to make your queries simple.

Comment: What you have is proper json for ES. Now the question you should be asking yourself is what do i want to search for/aggregate on etc. Based on your answer, you may want to specify a specific mapping for your json document or just let ES infer the mapping for you. If you post what search/aggregation you plan on doing we could probably suggest a mapping for you

Comment: dear all, thankyou for your fast response. I think i need to learn more about ES.